# Make Eclipse auto completion behave like Visual Studio intellisense?

Tags: eclipse

I'd like to have auto completion in Eclipse the way I am used to it from VS.

- When typing an open bracket the selected entry from the completion list is selected (Eclipse does not auto complete than)
- If the first point is not possible and I press enter, I'd like Eclipse not to insert brackets (I disabled inserting closing brackets already).

Any thoughts? Thanks,
Philipp

Answer (score 0):

you mean triggering code completion here:

```
myMethodCall(<^Space
```

If so, AFAIK this is currently not possible. Did you consider to report an enhancement request on this at Eclipse JDT?

You may also have a look on http://eclipse.org/recommenders which may be somewhat related to what you are looking for. Maybe you can start a discussion there about how you expect code completion to work in Eclipse in the recommenders forum here: http://eclipse.org/forums/eclipse.recommenders